# CEF3 client binary size optimization

Tags: optimization, filesize, chromium-embedded

I'm building CEF3 client app. The output of the binaries is `~105MB` in debug and `~90MB` in release. Is it possible to reduce the binaries size?

Comment: Use gyp define build_type=Official for release builds. It enables LTCG what saves about 10mb of release binary size. But if you already has this kind of build - then not so much options available. May be it is possible disable some unwanted functionality, but i'm never seen any info about... and actual outcome can be small. 70-90mb is normal size, depends on compiler, and CEF version, x86/x64.

Comment: See item number 6 at http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10567